# Swap not available after dual booting another linux distribution

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, swap

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and dual booting another Linux distro, I have my partitions like this

- /dev/sda1 is Ubuntu
- /dev/sda2 is distro 2
- /dev/sda3 is a shared swap between the two distros

the Ubuntu system monitor is showing that swap isn't available, I can temporarily activate it using `sudo swapon /dev/sda3` but it returns as it was after rebooting the PC

How can I enable swap is it was before, and should i set up two separate swap partitions for each distro?

Comment: Please check the UUID of your swap partition with `lsblk -f /dev/sda3` and compare the UUID with the entry in `/etc/fstab`. Most likely the UUID of your swap partition has been changed during the installation of the second distro.

Comment: @mook765 yes the UUID from the swap partition is different from the output of fstab, should I change  the fstab file?

Comment: Of course, you'll have to use the found UUID in the related fstab-entry.